# use js2-mode instead of js-mode in org babel source

Tags: org-babel, js2-mode

I want to use `js2-mode` instead of `js-mode` inside `org-babel` sources. Is there a way to define a mode for JavaScript inside those chunks?

```
#+begin_src js
console.log(1+1)
#+end_src
```

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, add it as an answer and then accept it once you're able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suddenly ran onto `org-src-lang-modes`, whereas the following snippet solved the problem:

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes
               '("js" . js2)
               )
```